# Can higher dimensional categories be represented as hypergraph and if not why?

Tags: graph-theory, category-theory, higher-category-theory, hypergraphs

As the diagrams of categories can be represented as graphs of objects and morphisms, I was wondering if (the diagrams of) higher-dimensional categories could be represented as hypergraphs, and if not why? And in the more general sense, what would be the best west to represent higher-dimensional categories (thinking of diagrams, but also data structures to represent them in programming languages)? And if we reverse the question, are there classes of categories whose diagrams would be best encoded as hypergraphs?

Comment: I disagree with the premise "The diagrams of categories can be represented as graphs of objects and morphisms." This really isn't true except in a very loose sense. The graph associated to a category forgets all the structure of composition, which is absolutely critical. Consider for example the category whose sole object is the set $\{1,2,3\}$ and whose morphisms are all functions from that set to itself with the usual notion of composition. As a graph this just looks like a dot with $27$ loops. But the category structure is quite intricate, e.g. some "loops" are invertible and others aren't.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I totally agree with you. The broad context in which I am asking this question is data structures and very low level high-performance programming. I work with bits and bytes, and I am trying to get a feeling how to best encode higher dimensional categories. I first try to get the data structure right, and then I'll add all the structure of composition you are talking about. If you have a suggestion of how to modify the question to better explain, that would be very welcomed.

Comment: You must consider the likely operations on your entity when designing its data structure / encoding. Poor encoding can vastly increase computational complexity, or worse, make certain operations uncomputable!